# Merging multi-dimensional objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**Default Object**

```
var default_obj = {
    "cloud": {
        "something_1": {
            "view": false,
            "create": false
        },
        "something_2": {
            "view": false,
            "create": false
        },
        "something_3": {
            "view": false,
            "create": false
        },
    }
}
```

**Object to Merge**

```
var merge_obj = {
    "cloud": {
        "something_1": {
            "view": true,
            "create": true
        },
        "something_2": {
            "view": false,
            "create": false
        }
    }
}
```

**After Merge**

```
var merge_obj = {
    "cloud": {
        "something_1": {
            "view": true,
            "create": true
        },
        "something_2": {
            "view": false,
            "create": false
        }
        "something_3": {
            "view": false,
            "create": false
        }
    }
}
```

I basically want the second object to overwrite everything in the default object, HOWEVER, if there is new pieces of information in the default object that isn't found in the second one, to include that.

Just by doing `{ ...default_obj, ...merge_obj }` works for the first part of overwriting but it leaves out `something_3`

### Edit

Just want to note that the objects will not always hold `view`, or `create` it could really be anything but it will never go any deeper in dimensions.

Comment: Please, post how the object should look like after the merge. When it find two keys with same name, what should output?

Comment: @CalvinNunes edited, sorry for the confusion

Comment: It should replace the objects that already exists? Example: `something_1` have all values set to false, but the merge shows it as true. So it gets the values from the `merge_obj`  right?

Comment: @CalvinNunes yup, however you'll see that `something_3` is not in `merge_obj` so it needs to be added.

Comment: Bryan, did you see my answer (the last answer here) ?

Answer (score 1):

This function will do the merge between the two objects.

```
function merge(obj, src) {
     Object.keys(src).forEach(function(key) {          
       if (typeof src[key] === 'object') {
         if (typeof obj[key] === 'undefined') obj[key] = {};

         obj[key] = merge(obj[key], src[key]);
       } else {

         obj[key] = src[key];
       }
     });

  return obj;
}
```

`merge(default_obj, merge_obj)`

But there is available libraries like lodash that already do that. Example: 
`_.merge(default_obj, merge_obj);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a built-in for this, but I would have thought just looping through if not?

```
for(var x in merge_obj['cloud']) {
   default_obj['cloud'][ x ] = merge_obj['cloud'][x];
}
```

Haven't tested, but think that would work as it would overwrite if already there and insert if not.

Comment: This would assume that `cloud` is defined which isn't always the case. But I'll try and edit it to see if it works. Sometimes the simple answer is the easiest

Comment: Ah, I see. I certainly agree with the last point. I guess it depends on how dynamic the objects are. Possibly, as luis has suggested, some kind of recursive call would resolve this, but it could get messy quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You need recursion to iterate through the properties, this function can be created manually but I suggest to use any library or use an already tested code, this is because of the similitudes between Array and Object and some other conditions.

Here is a link to an example https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-deep-merge

Answer (score 0):

Try this npm library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-extend

Otherwise, you'll have to recurse into each child object to merge them.